# Camera on surfaceview android rotation

Tags: android, camera, surfaceview

I'm developing an application with camera and I use surfaceview to preview the camera, so when I start the preview the camera is rotated 90 degree or something like that it is in landscape but I hold my phone in portrait.

How can I make it start in regular position. The photos that I take are in landscape.

```
parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
parameters.set("rotation", 90);
```

Comment: consider forcing your activity's orientation to `landscape` in the manifest file, and overriding the configchanges method. also, add configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" in the manifest for your activity. this may fix the view you are experiencing

Answer (score 0):

well you can pass your activity reference to surfaceview and check for orientation on surfaceCreated method by this code

```
if(yourActivity.getRequestedOrientation()==ActivityInfo.LANDSCAPE)
{

//perform you setting here

}
else if(yourActivity.getRequestedOrientation()==ActivityInfo.PORTRAIT)
{
//perform accordingly
}
```

Comment: yea but the image is in landscape I want to see the preview and the picture taken to be the same. if I put it in landscape mode the image is in portrait but the preview is not the same. i think you got me ? :)

Comment: on LG optimus one I got the screen in landscape mode and the preview is good is real and also the photo when I take it. On Xperia x10 mini in landscape mode the preview is good but the image that I take is rotated fo 90 degree I use this to rotate the image 

parameters.setRotation(90);